# Reading in txt File -Matlab Line Extraction with Logic

Tags: matlab, text, input, textscan

Currently stumped with reading in a .txt file with the general layout described below:

(The .txt file follows this general layout "N" times)

```
-----------------------------------
Header Info 1
Desired data 1
More data
More data
-----------------------------------
Header Info 2
Desired data 2
More data
-----------------------------------
Header Info 3
Desired data 3
More data
More data
More data
More data
----------------------------------
Header Info N
Desired data N
More data
More data
More data
CLOSING DATA LINE
```

I would like to extract only the "Desired data" along with the final "CLOSING DATA LINE" but the twist is that there is varying "More data" lines in between that inhibits a simple line-by-line extraction pattern. There can be 0-hundreds of these "More data" lines...

I do know that my desired data is 2 lines below every "---------------" and was wondering if there is some sort of way to "detect" a "---------" and execute a line extraction 2 lines below that. Further, to get the final line, trying to implement logic to extract that line before.

I've thought of simply going through every line with fgetl and having if statements capture the "---------" with a strcmpare which seems pretty "brute force-ish". Any lightweight or efficient solutions?

Comment: Matlab + file reading + strings in said file + **lightweight**?:) Are you intent on using matlab? I'd probably use a well-constructed `system` call to a few unix utilities, then parse that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following example, assuming your text file named `a.txt`:

```
% open and read file
f = fopen('a.txt');
d = textscan(f, '%s', 'Delimiter', '');

% since d is a cell containing another cell array
dd = d{1};

% index of '-------' lines
myidx = find(cellfun(@(DD)all(ismember(DD, '-')), dd));

% output data
mydata = [dd(myidx + 2); dd(end)];

% close file
fclose(f);
```

Using `all(ismember(dd{k}, '-'))` gives you 1 if line `dd{k}` contains all `-`, and 0 if not. Then execute `cellfun` for that to get the array of 1 and 0 values, where 1 represents the line with all `-`. Finally, use `find` to get index of the 1 values.